# Why I'm not able to declare variable of parameterized type initialized with null?

Tags: scala, generics, traits

Why doesn't this work?

```
trait testtrait[T] {
  var ob:T = null
}
```

then scalac testtrait.scala produces

```
testtrait.scala:2: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Null(null)
 required: T
  var ob:T = null
             ^
one error found
```

I'm using Scala 2.9

Comment: Why are `var` instead of a `val`. Generally in traits you don't want either. You want a `def` instead.

Comment: @wheaties Not true. You might have very good reasons to want a `val` or even a `var` in a trait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't say why exactly, but underscore notion (which is shortcut for *default value for type, which is null for objects*) will work fine:

```
trait testtrait[T] {
  var ob:T = _
}
```

More dreaded workaround is `asInstanceOf` cast, but I found underscore better alternative.

```
trait testtrait[T] {
  var ob:T = null.asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`null` is a value of type `Null`, but not *any* type has `Null` as a subtype, only `AnyRef`-derived ones (except `Nothing`, of course). Suppose that you did something like

```
object SomeObj extends testtrait[Int]
```

What `SomeObj.ob` should be equal to? It is an `Int`, so it does not have `null` as a possible value.

As it is said in other answers, you should use underscore syntax to set default value for the type.

Comment: But why upper bounded type parameter doesn't work? I mean `testtrait[T <: AnyRef]`

Comment: @om-nom-nom, because `Nothing <: AnyRef` and `Nothing` does not have `null`. `T >: Null <: AnyRef` should work. I guess I was slightly incorrect in this regard in my answer, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The bottom type of *all* types is `Nothing`. That means any type `T`, not otherwise constrained, can be `Nothing`, and `null` is not a `Nothing` (in fact, no value is).

So, to be able to assign `null`, you'd have to write it `[T >: Null]` (`T` is a supertype of `Null`).

On the other hand, you can initialize it to the default value using `var ob: T = _`. However, be aware that for any `AnyVal`, `T` will be boxed and assigned `null` instead of, say, 0, which can lead to unexpected results.